# Cordova How to display SQLite data into kendo ListView?

Tags: cordova, kendo-mobile

I'm able to get the sqlite data to display on Icenium console window but not ListView. Here is my code:

```
var dbresult;

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DemoTable', [], querySuccess, onError);
}
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    dbresult = results;
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    $("#displayResult").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("ID =  " + results.rows.item(i).id + "Data = " + results.rows.item(i).data);
    }

    $("#myListView").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource:  kendo.data.DataSource.read({data: results.rows.item().id, group: "id"}),
        template: $("#myTemplate").html(),
        fixedHeaders: true
    });
}
```

In index.html

```
<div id="myListView"></div>

<!--Template-->
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
<h3>${id}</h3>
<p >${data}</p>
</script>
```

I think that is something wrong about my dataSource but don't know how?

can any1 help?

thanks.

Comment: It certainly sounds like you're on the right track.  SUGGESTION: go to [this link](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-using-the-phonegap-database-api/) and look at 
Christophe Coenraets' "employeelist.js" example.  Also note how his index.html wraps employeelist.js.

Comment: answer found, see below

Answer (score 1):

found the answer, just put the sql query result into an array. Then use the array in the template.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code was that you are reading the property of an item instead of the array containing the rows of data.

dataSource:  `kendo.data.DataSource.read({data: results.rows.item().id, group: "id"}),`

should rather use the rows:

dataSource:  `kendo.data.DataSource.read({data: results.rows, group: "id"}),`